# AWS CLI commands on JENKINS

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, jenkins, amazon-s3, terminal

I'm trying to write a script that with the help of **Jenkins** will look at the updated files in **git**, download it and will encrypt them using **AWS KMS**. I have a working script that does it all and the file is downloaded to the **Jenkins repository** on local server. But my problem is encrypting this file in Jenkins repo. Basically, when I encrypt files on local computer, I use the command:

```
aws kms encrypt --key-id xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx --plaintext fileb://file.json --output text --query CiphertextBlob | base64 --decode > Encrypted-data.json
```

and all is ok, but if I try to do it with Jenkins I get an error that the AWS command not found.
Does somebody know how to solve this problem and how do I make it run AWS through Jenkins? 
Here is my working code which breaks down on the last line:

```
bom_sniffer() { 

  head -c3 "$1" | LC_ALL=C grep -qP '\xef\xbb\xbf'; 
  if [ $? -eq 0 ] 
  then 
    echo "BOM SNIFFER DETECTED BOM CHARACTER IN FILE \"$1\""
    exit 1
  fi
}
check_rc() {
  # exit if passed in value is not = 0
  # $1 = return code
  # $2 = command / label
  if [ $1 -ne 0 ]
  then
    echo "$2 command failed"
    exit 1
  fi
}

# finding files that differ from this commit and master
echo 'git fetch'
check_rc $? 'echo git fetch'
git fetch
check_rc $? 'git fetch'
echo 'git diff --name-only origin/master'
check_rc $? 'echo git diff'

diff_files=`git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT | xargs`
check_rc $? 'git diff'
for x in ${diff_files}
do
  echo "${x}"
  cat ${x}
  bom_sniffer "${x}"
  check_rc $? "BOM character detected in ${x},"
  aws configure kms encrypt --key-id xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx --plaintext fileb://${x} --output text --query CiphertextBlob | base64 --decode > Encrypted-data.json

done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After discussion with you this is how this issue was resolved :

First corrected the command by removing `configure` from it.

Installed the awscli for the jenkins user :
`pip install awscli --user`

Used the absolute path of `aws` in your script
for eg. say if it's in ~/.local/bin/ use `~/.local/bin/aws kms encrypt --key-id xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx --plaintext fileb://${x} --output text --query CiphertextBlob | base64 --decode > Encrypted-data.json` in your script.
Or add the path of aws in PATH.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply , batMan , my path to Jenkins is : /var/lib/jenkins/ , and path to aws is : jenkins@root:/home/andrejka$ which awk
/usr/bin/awk

Can you please show me example to execute command ?

Comment: @Andrej: Sorry I mistakenly wrote `/var/usr/awk` instead of `/var/usr/aws`. Editing Answer. Also can you give me the output for `which aws` after doing ssh on the server.

Comment: 1)andrejka@root:~2)$ su jenkins
3)Password: xxxxxxxx
4)jenkins@root:/home/andrejka 5)$ which aws 
6)jenkins@root:/home/andrejka 7)$ which awk 
8)/usr/bin/awk     , Only which awk is reply , which aws don't reply if i understand your correctly.

Comment: Ok that means `aws` is not installed on remote machine. On your local it is installed but on server it's not. I don't know if it should be on the server or not. You can install aws cli on jenkins machine too.  I strongly recommend you to talk to some senior in your organisation before doing this. Steps mentioned here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html.

Comment: i can show you what i have in teamviewer if you can see , please i really need aws cli on jankins.

Comment: @Andrej: You can follow the steps mentioned here : https://cloudacademy.com/blog/aws-cli-a-beginners-guide/ If you face issues then I can help you on Teamviewer.

Comment: i already have aws cli on my local computer , and already configure it. now i try to write in my jenkins script to echo $PATH , and get this : /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
Finished: SUCCESS 
i don't know where is a problem, can you just look what i have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153026/discussion-between-batman-and-andrej).